# outlook search options

Tags: vba, search, outlook

I have on outlook access to public folders. On the public folders incoming mails with an attachment pdf form Customers. The current situation is I need to search all 50 folders one by one for keywords in the attachment to find which one is for me. I’m trying to

1. Find a way to search all folders and subfolders at one’s.
   2.find a way to alert me when incoming messages with the keyword as arrived.
   Thank you very much

I tried all possible settings and tried VBA macro

Comment: Add your code to the question. Search the site for previously answered questions about public folders, finding text in attachments and ItemAdd. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What exactly have you tried in VBA?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Find a way to search all folders and subfolders at one’s.

Use the `AdvancedSearch` method of the `Application` class from the Outlook object model. The key benefits of using the `AdvancedSearch` method in Outlook are:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the `AdvancedSearch` method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The `Restrict` and `Find`/`FindNext` methods can be applied to a particular `Items` collection (see the `Items` property of the `Folder` class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the `IsInstantSearchEnabled` property of the `Store` class).
- You can stop the search process at any moment using the `Stop` method of the `Search` class.

Read more about that method in the article I wrote for the technical blog - [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/).

> 2.find a way to alert me when incoming messages with the keyword as arrived. Thank you very much

You can handle the `NewMailEx` event of the `Application` class in Outlook. This event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, `MailItem`, `MeetingItem`, or `SharingItem`. The `EntryIDsCollection` string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item. Use the Entry ID to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item.